# C++ - system command

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program which is mainly used for video processing. Inside the program, I am launching the `system` command in order to obtain pass the processed videos to some other binaries to postprocess them.

I have a while loop towards infinite and I am launching the system command inside the loop every time. The thing is that at a certain point I am receiving the -1 return code from the `system` command. What could be the reason for that?

Inside the system command I am just calling a binary file with the adequate parameters from the main project.

The `system` command which I want to execute is actually a shell file.
In this file I am extracting the main feature from the video and passing them through a SVM model from a 3D party library in order to obtain the the desired classification.

```
./LiveGestureKernel ./Video ./SvmVideo
./mat4libsvm31 -l SvmVideoLabels < SvmVideo > temp_test_file
./svm-predict temp_test_file svm_model temp_output_file
cat < temp_output_file
rm -f temp_*
```

After a certain number of iterations through the while loop, it just won't execute the script file and I cannot figure out the reason for this. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your environment, but it could be the program you are executing is returning -1

Comment: The return code depends on what you're executing. We need more info.

Comment: Have you tried looking up information on the `system` library call?

Comment: Do you launch these postprocessing commands with `&` so they're in the background? You could be running out of processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `-1` from the call to `system()`, you should first examine the contents of `errno` - that will most likely tell you what your specific problem is.

The one thing to watch out for is that the return value from `system` is an implementation-defined one in the case where you pass it a non-NULL command, so it's possible that `-1` may be coming from your actual executable.

Your best bet in that case is to print out (or otherwise log) the command being executed on failure (and possibly *all* the time), so that you can check what happens with the same arguments when you execute it directly from a command line or shell.